# Ember 1.0.0: Ember.State has been moved into a plugin: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am migrating an Ember rc7 project to Ember 1.0.0.  I have this unusual error:

```
Ember.State has been moved into a plugin: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states
```

I have the error only if I use a combination of Ember.js 1.0.0 in combination with Ember data 0.13.  If I include the extra ember-states lib, then everything works fine.

What is the reason of this change ?  Why do I need an additional lib ?

If I use Ember.js 1.0.0 in combination with Ember data 1.0.0 beta.1, then this error does not occur.

I hope somebody can explain why this additional lib seems to be needed in some cases ?

Marc

Answer (score 15):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3191) Ember itself does not use `Ember.State` internally anymore, and as of this [Ember Data commit](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/bf8497814e49cedcbd52922345287394255f637f) Ember Data did not depend on the `Ember.State` implementation (a new/better way to handle internal state in Ember Data was used instead).

Since neither library has a dependency for `Ember.State` they moved it to its own package, which can be included manually if you still require it.

Github repository for [`Ember.State` can be found here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states)

Using this table you can see that when using Ember Data 0.13 and Ember 1.0.0, Ember Data 0.13 tries to use `Ember.State`, but Ember 1.0.0 does not provide it and causes your error.

```
+-------------------------+------------------+----------------------+
|         Library         | Uses Ember.State | Provides Ember.State |
+-------------------------+------------------+----------------------+
| Ember rc7               | no               | yes                  |
| Ember 1.0.0             | no               | no                   |
| Ember Data 0.13         | yes              | no                   |
| Ember Data 1.0.0 beta 1 | no               | no                   |
+-------------------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thx. Very good explanation! I am now trying to migrate to Ember data 1.0.0 so that I can remove the dependency ...  but run into a lot of issues (I was using transactions very often).