# Uncaught Error: Ember.State has been moved into a plugin

Tags: ember.js

Nowhere in my code do I reference Ember.State. I don't know what it is. If I am using the latest Ember 1.0.0 and ember-data .13 Why am I getting this error and what do I do about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember 1.0.0: Ember.State has been moved into a plugin: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558754/ember-1-0-0-ember-state-has-been-moved-into-a-plugin-https-github-com-emberj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because **ember data 0.13** used `Ember.State` but **ember 1.0.0** has moved it away into a plugin as the error states. To get rid of the error you should use **ember data 1.0.0 beta 1** in tandem with **ember 1.0.0**.

All the releases are now easy accessible under: http://emberjs.com/builds/

And before you hit some other to you unexplained errors you should read this ember data transition guide: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Hope it helps.